# SQL interval of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a project that needs the interval of a data for eg

I have a data that is `DECLARE @Time datetime = 'Jan  1 1900 9:54AM'` the expected outcome would be `1900-01-01 09:30:00` but with this query

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundTime] (@Time datetime, @RoundTo float)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @RoundedTime smalldatetime
DECLARE @Multiplier float

SET @Multiplier= 24.0/@RoundTo

SET @RoundedTime= ROUND(CAST(CAST(CONVERT(varchar,@Time,121) AS datetime) AS float) * @Multiplier,0)/@Multiplier

RETURN @RoundedTime
```

END

I got this result `1900-01-01 10:00:00` and please enlighten me on how you did it. I am using SQL database btw.

EDIT 1: I use `0.5` as the `@RoundTo` parameter
EDIT 2: and this is how I use the function `,CONVERT(varchar, CONVERT(time,[dbo].[RoundTime](CAST(CAST([INTERVAL] as datetime) as varchar),0.5)), 108) as [Interval]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my query with

```
 DECLARE @RoundedTime smalldatetime
 DECLARE @Multiplier float

 SET @Multiplier= 24.0/@RoundTo

 SET @RoundedTime= DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, @Time)/30*30, 0)

 RETURN @RoundedTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is declared to return a `datetime`.  This is the proper, internal format for date/time values.

You can use `format()` in the more recent versions of SQL Server, or something like:

```
convert(varchar(255), @RoundedTime, 109)
```

BUT . . . do this *after* you have called the function.  The function should return a `datetime`.  Your format is just a presentation format.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[RoundTime](@Time datetime)
RETURNS smalldatetime
as
Begin

Declare @RoundedTime  smalldatetime
SET @RoundedTime=
(Select 
case when datepart(minute,@Time)=0 and  datepart(second,@Time)=0 then  convert(varchar(10),@Time,121) 
     when datepart(minute,@Time)>30 and  datepart(second,@Time)=0 then dateadd(mi,30,cast(convert(varchar(14),@Time,121)+'00' as datetime))
     when datepart(minute,@Time)=30 and  datepart(second,@Time)=0 then cast(convert(varchar(16),@Time,121) as datetime)
     when datepart(minute,@Time)<30 and  datepart(second,@Time)=0 then dateadd(mi,0,cast(convert(varchar(14),@Time,121)+'00' as datetime))
end as 'Date') 

return @RoundedTime

end
```

Comment: @vian-ojeda-garcia Try this, just wanted to know what is the purpose of @@RoundTo float parameter

Comment: @vian-ojeda-garcia If you can share an example of the wrong data so that I can correct it...

Comment: it displays more data than it should

Comment: because i also use this function for my query filter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144307/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-and-vian-ojeda-garcia).